Advice creating and saving a logo with Apple II HGR graphics (BASIC prog)
I'm working on a small project with a local association to revive and illustrate what can be done with an Apple II. They have both a II c and e models.
With the low res GR mode, I use HLIN, VLIN and PLOT to draw the logo.
I'm looking at the way to do the same with the HGR. I understand that I can only use HPLOT. Somehow it would have been nice to have some ways to fill shapes.
I tried the DRAW function which seems to load an image that's stored in the memory, as well as the ROT for rotation. Once I create the logo with HPLOT, is there a way to save the data to reuse it with a DRAW function to move, rotate it?
Note that I'm programming with BASIC.
thanks

You probably know this already (but not stated in question) - to fill in HGR, use a series of HPLOT x,y TO n,m statements, specifying the coords of the opposite boundaries of the shape in (x,y) and (n,m). Some useful examples.

Note that DRAW and ROT are for shape tables, and have nothing to do with anything you draw with HPLOT.

You say "illustrate what can be done with an Apple II", but as shown some of the comments, some further clarification might help. Do you want to write only Applesoft code to create something on the hires screen, or are you willing to write something superior utilizing assembly language subroutines, or would you like to prepare a hires image with other software and then display that image?

There is no built-in mechanism for this in AppleSoft, but there is a 3rd party application from Beagle Bros. software called Shape Mechanic which has a "capture shape" function. This program will allow you to load a HGR image file (or just pull up the one currently in RAM), capture it as a shape, and save it as a binary file.
I'm assuming the BASIC program you're writing is being saved to disk so you can run it again. As well, for completeness you are aware that you can save the HGR image to a file by doing BSAVE MY.IMAGE,A$2000,L$2000 (replace A$2000 with A$4000 if on 'HGR2' page).
Shape Mechanic has menu options to load image files from disk, but by default will just bring up whatever is currently occupying the 'HGR1' graphic page. You don't want to make the image too large since the tool can only handle 8192 vectors which is really a representation of image complexity and thus difficult to clearly describe here. However, the manual would suggest keeping it within 63x48 pixels. The 'Outline' function shows what you're capturing, and you can move it around with the arrow keys. You can increase the X size of the outline by pressing '1', and increase the Y by pressing '2'. Use arrows to resize, return to accept. Get what you want, and 'S'ave it.
To use the shape, you can load it into RAM and set AppleSoft's vector to point to that.
For example, let's say I saved a file "MY.SHAPES".
]SH=16384  :  REM ** ram location to use **
]BLOAD MY.SHAPES,A16384
]POKE 232,SH-INT(SH/256)*256 : POKE 233,INT(SH/256)  :  REM ** set vector **
]HGR : HCOLOR=3
]DRAW 1 at 10,10

The above will load the shape table generated by Shape Mechanic, tell AppleSoft how to find the shape table in memory, set high-res graphics mode, set color to white, and draw it at the X,Y offset of 10,10. You can then ROTate or SCALE it however you want.

Even with a utility to produce shapes for use with DRAW and XDRAW, I find myself dubious about their usefulness, given how much work they go through for every single pixel that they produce.  Was their performance ever good enough to make them worthwhile?

@supercat it's all relative. If you want fast animation, Applesoft BASIC isn't really your best choice to start with. Shape tables are compact and much faster than plotting an intricate shape directly. Blitting bitmaps is faster but there's no support for that in Applesoft.

@fadden: The code to process shape tables is simultaneously bulky and slow.  A utility that generates shapes that can be drawn slowly via DRAW command would seem less useful than one which would produce a blob that included machine code to draw things much more quickly using ampersand-hook, USR, or CALL commands.

@supercat: you're absolutely right, there are better ways to do it than with AppleSoft shape tables; I can't think of a single commercial title that used them. The only advantage to shape tables is that they're built-in and don't require a machine language driver to use. That being said, the question did ask about the DRAW function which is shape tables. If there is an alternative available that the question's author can use from BASIC that would work better, I'm sure they'd be happy to hear about it.

@bjb: I didn't do a whole lot of graphics back in the day, but the stuff I did generally used machine code.  Loading and running machine code from within BASIC is no less convenient than setting up shape tables, and if memory serves my main approach was to define a set of 255 7x8 shapes and then use a machine language routine that would, for any non-blank byte on the text screen, draw that shape on the graphics screen at the corresponding position.  That approach was somewhat limited, but vastly faster than anything with shape tables.

@bjb: A routine to take over character-out and draw text on the hi-res screen existed early on in Apple II history, since Tawala's Last Redoubt was an early game that could do precisely that; I wonder why Apple didn't bundle any such thing on the DOS 3.3 system disk?

@supercat: a hi-res character generator was part of the "Apple-Vision" demo, as binary code and data embedded in Integer BASIC. An HRCG was a key part of the DOS Toolkit, which included the RIBBIT animation demo. The code to process shape tables isn't especially bulky, as it's enmeshed with the rest of the hi-res code.

@bjb: shape tables were used in multiple early titles, such as Rescue at Rigel, Temple of Apshai, and Global War, where they were used to hold fonts and other shapes. Applesoft not only drew them for you, it would load them from cassette and set up the pointers with the SHLOAD command. They can be found in later games like Starship Commander, and drew the stars in the display in Galactic Empire. If you drew alternating columns you could even get color.

The most important things to understand if one wants to do hires color graphics are:

Every horizontal group of seven pixels has a mode bit, which selects between two color sets (green and magenta, or orange and aqua), and that HCOLOR= will set that mode bit when drawing colors 4-7 and clear it when drawing 0-3.

Pixels with odd coordinates will light up green or orange; those with even coordinates will light up magenta or aqua.  Pixels are a bit fuzzy, and if green and orange pixels are lit next to each other, the area of overlap will be white.
Likewise if orange and aqua pixels are shown next to each other.

Using HCOLOR= 0 or 4 will cause drawing commands set both even and odd pixels to black.  Using 3 or 7 will cause both even and odd pixels to be set to "on".  Colors 1 and 5 will set even pixels to black and odd to "on"; colors 2 and 6 will set odd pixels to black and even to "on".  In general, this means that when trying to draw things in color at arbitrary coordinates, half of the pixels one is trying to draw won't show up.


Although HPLOT can draw diagonal lines, I think it's better to think in terms of vertical and horizontal stripes.  When drawing things in color, using vertical stripes and only drawing at even or odd coordinates may speed up program execution.
